# Ruby on Rails: Displaying ["A", "B"] Individually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When I output the data saved as a checkbox (int: text) using `<%= b.category %>`, it outputs `["A", "B"]`and is enclosed in `[]` and `""`, as shown below. I would like to be able to display on separately.→`A, B`

Comment: `b.category` is an `Array`, I guess? That's not a great method/database column name if it represents a list of properties; a plural field should ideally have a plural name, i.e. `b.categories`, not `b.category`.

Comment: Anyway, the simplest way to display this like you describe would be to join the array elements into a `String`, split by a comma: `<%= b.category.join(', ') %>`

Comment: See: https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/join

Comment: Or maybe you're asking how to create a separate checkbox for each category??? In which case, loop over them: `<% b.category.each do |category| %>` -- again, this is why having a singular method name for a plural attribute is confusing. It would be better to have this like: `<% b.categories.each do |category| %>`

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I got an error for undefined method `each' for "[\"A\", \"B\"]":String.

Comment: OK, so it’s actually JSON (a structured string), not an array. You would need to call JSON.parse on it first.

Comment: I see, using JSON.parse, I was able to do it successfully. Thank you very much for your help. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `.join()`. [Docs for Array.join()](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/join)

I am assuming you just mixed up the pluralization cases.

```
<% categories_string = b.category.join(', ') %>
<%= categories_string %>
```

Or more succinctly:

```
<%= b.category.join(', ') %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got an error for undefined method `join' for "[\"A\", \"B\"]":String.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're interested in a more human-readable list, I would go for something like:

```
    arr = ["A","B","C"]
    last = arr.pop
    human_arr = arr.join(", ") + ", and " + last.to_s
    human_arr
```

which gives:

```
    "A, B, and C"
```

I went for an Oxford comma, but that's up to you!

## Update

And as Stefan mentioned, the above code is covered with the method [to_sentence](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-to_sentence)

Comment: Or just use [`to_sentence`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-to_sentence)

Comment: @Stefan: Oh, silly me: that seems to be 'a bit' faster.